# how to (logout) destroy codeigniter session? after clearing browser cache my logout code is work fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies, browser-cache

This is my Logout code.

```
$unset_data = array('user_id' => '', 'logged_in' => '', 'user' => '', 'user_role' => '', 'user_status' => '', 'user_name' => '', 'user_reg_date' => '', 'user_avatar' => '');
$this->session->unset_userdata($unset_data);
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect( base_url(), 'location', 301);
```

This code work fine after clearing browser cache, But its not good. what i will do for logout. is there any `.htaccess` or `config.php` setting for browser cache.

Comment: This issue i am facing only in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Why u using both $this->session->sess_destroy(); and unset it will destroy every thing if use $this->session->sess_destroy();

Comment: And if redirect( base_url(), 'location', 301); would it be better to redirect to login page. redirect(login); no need for base_url in redirect

Comment: visit to this site webaccentors.com where problem is facing.

Comment: sorry do not want to join up

Comment: not for join up just give you for look up, why i am not redirect to login. thanks dude.

Comment: As said redirect( base_url(), 'location', 301); should be redirect('login-controller'); or redirect('index.php/login-controller');or redirect('/'); you do not need base_url in redirect you  also may need to set some routes.php And only use one or the other of sessions.